# Problems with Like button

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I use for my site www.spazio-psicologia.com facebook plugin to have social integration with facebook platform.
I have one problem: like button seems to work proprely collecting click of who likes my articles, but sometimes, without any reasons, it clears all click collected and restart counting from zero.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Laura

Comment: Does it happen when you change the permalink structure of your website?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to put like button in your site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Just click `Get Code`, put that in your template. Facebook will do the rest.